# Not getting result of HttpClient.PostAsync()

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

Developing a .NET Core web application that need to call a Json REST Api.

The caller :

```
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            AuthorizationUser user = new AuthorizationUser { User = "<user>", Application = "<app>" };

            var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(new Uri("http://localhost:8081/Roles"), content);
            // ...
        }
```

The callee :

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(AuthorizationUser user)
    {
        try
        {
            user = FillRoles(user);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, user);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex);
        }
    }
```

The model (in caller and callee):

```
public class AuthorizationUser
{

    public AuthorizationUser() // Added thanks to CodeFuller
    { }

    public AuthorizationUser(string user, string application)
    {
        User = user ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(user));
        Application = application ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(application));

    }
    public string User { get; set; }
    public string Application { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

When reaching the breakpoint in the callee, received `user` is always null.
I tried to add `[FromBody]` and `[FromUri]` before it but same result.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your problem, getting correctly filled user with `User` and `Application` fields.

Seems like some error during model binding happens. To diagnose the problem check the following:

1. What is the value of `ActionContext.ModelState.IsValid` in `Post()` method. Is it `true` or `false`?
2. If it's false, check collection `ActionContext.ModelState.Values` in debugger. It should contain model binding errors.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, problem half solved. Checked 1. was false. Checked 2. : `Unable to find a constructor to use for type AuthorizationUser. A class should either have a default constructor, one constructor with arguments or a constructor marked with the JsonConstructor attribute. Path 'Headers', line 1, position 11.`

Comment: So I added a default constructor (add one but it was `private`). 

Now, `user`is not null but values in it are null and `ModelState.IsValid` is true.

Comment: And now ModelState.IsValid is true?

Comment: Try setting breakpoints in AuthorizationUser setters in callee, do they hit?

Comment: Nope, they don't hit. Constructor is but not setters.

Comment: Could you update your question with exact definition of AuthorizationUser in callee. Current definition at least does not have a constructor. Little things could matter. Also HTTP body sent by the client would be very helpful.

Comment: This helped me definitively to understood my errors. I cleaned all and recompiled and worked. So, just thanks :)